# Relationship method must return an object of type in Laravel FormBuilder

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with laravel 5.1 . In **EDIT** function I am getting the following error:

LogicException in Model.php line 2673:
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

here is my controller function:

```
public function edit(FormBuilder $formBuilder, $id) {
    $result  = News::findOrFail($id);
    $form    = $formBuilder->create('employment_bank\Forms\NewsForm', [
        'method' => 'PUT',
        'model' => $result,
        'url' => route($this->route.'update', $id)
    ])->remove('save');
    return view($this->content.'edit', compact('form'));
}
```

News model :

```
protected $table = 'news';
public static $rules = [
    'title' => 'required',
];

protected $guarded = ['id', '_token'];
protected $fillable = ['title', 'photo', 'status', 'summary', 'description', 'news_category_id', 'slug'];
public $timestamps = true;

public function news_category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('employment_bank\Models\NewsCategory', 'news_category_id');
}
```

And the form is:

```
public function buildForm(){

    $category = NewsCategory::lists('title', 'id')->all();
    $status = array(1 => "Publish",0 => "Draft");

    $this->add('title', 'text', [
        'attr' => ['required', 'maxlength' => '255', 'placeholder'=> 'News title'],
        'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group'] // Shows the wrapper for each e
    ]);
    $this->add('photo', 'file', [
        'attr'  =>  ['id' => 'photo_url', 'accept'=>'.jpg, .png', 'title'=>'Please upload a passport size photograph'],
        'label' =>  'Photo'
    ]);
    $this->add('news_category_id', 'select', [
        'choices' => $category,
        'empty_value' => '==== Select Category ===',
        'label' => 'Category',
        'attr' => ['required'],
    ]);
    $this->add('status', 'select', [
        'choices' => $status,
        'empty_value' => '==== Status ===',
        'label' => 'status',
        'attr' => ['required'],
    ]);
    $this->add('summary', 'textarea', [
        'attr' => ['maxlength' => '255', 'rows' => '5', 'placeholder'=> 'News summary'],
        'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group'] // Shows the wrapper for each e
        //'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-6'] // Shows the wrapper for each e
    ]);
    $this->add('description', 'textarea', [
        'attr' => ['rows' => '10', 'placeholder'=> 'News description'],
        'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group'] // Shows the wrapper for each e
        //'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-6'] // Shows the wrapper for each e
    ]);

    $this->add('save', 'submit', [
        'attr' => ['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary col-md-12']
    ]);

    $this->add('update', 'submit', [
        'attr' => ['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-success col-md-12']
    ]);
}
```

Error in full:

```
    LogicException in Model.php line 2673:
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
in Model.php line 2673
at Model->getRelationshipFromMethod('save') in Model.php line 2643
at Model->getRelationValue('save') in Model.php line 2585
at Model->getAttribute('save') in Model.php line 3339
at Model->__get('save') in Model.php line 3411
at Model->__isset('save') in helpers.php line 529
at object_get(object(News), 'save') in FormField.php line 191
at FormField->getModelValueAttribute(object(News), 'save') in FormField.php line 113
at FormField->setupValue() in FormField.php line 100
at FormField->__construct('save', 'submit', object(NewsForm), array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary col-md-12'), 'real_name' => 'save')) in Form.php line 161
at Form->makeField('save', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary col-md-12'))) in Form.php line 185
at Form->add('save', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary col-md-12'))) in NewsForm.php line 46
at NewsForm->buildForm() in FormBuilder.php line 53
at FormBuilder->create('employment_bank\Forms\NewsForm', array('method' => 'PUT', 'model' => object(News), 'url' => 'http://localhost:8000/master/news/1')) in NewsController.php line 104
at NewsController->edit(object(FormBuilder), '1')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(NewsController), 'edit'), array(object(FormBuilder), 'news' => '1')) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('edit', array(object(FormBuilder), 'news' => '1')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(NewsController), object(Route), 'edit') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(NewsController), object(Route), object(Request), 'edit') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'employment_bank\Http\Controllers\Master\NewsController', 'edit') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 708
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AuthenticateAdmin.php line 33
at AuthenticateAdmin->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthenticateAdmin), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 710
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('/var/www/jobportal/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NewsForm two button (**save** and **update**) was treated as a keyword.

```
$this->add('save', 'submit', [
    'attr' => ['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary col-md-12']
]);

$this->add('update', 'submit', [
    'attr' => ['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-success col-md-12']
]);
```

Changing the button to **save** to **save news** and **update** to **update news** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like somewhere in your app, you are trying to access a non-existent method on a model instance, that's why it is searching for a relation.

Can you post the full stack trace of the error?